# toastr javascript SyntaxError

Tags: javascript

i am tring to implement a toastr with yes or no buttons

and i get this

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

this is my JavaScript Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function detele() {
        toastr.warning("<div>confirmer la suppression?</div>" +
          "<div class ='btn-group pull-right'> " +
          "<button type ='button' id='confirmationYes' class ='btn btn-xs btn-primary'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></i>Oui</button>" +
          "<button type ='button' class ='btn btn-xs btn-default clear'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></i>Non</button>" +
          "</div>", 
          "DeleteConfirmation", 
          {
            allowHtml: true,
            closeButton: true,
            onShown: function() {
              $("#confirmationYes").click(function() {
                  toastr.success("Done");
                });
              }
          });
        };
    </script>
```

the console shows that the error is in this line

> ```
>  "<div class="btn-group pull-right"> " +
> ```
>
> i just dont get it !

Comment: You completely messed up your closing brackets at the end (doesnt explain the missing `)` though)

Comment: *"the console shows that the error is in this line"* Your quote of that line after that sentence uses different (and incorrect) quotes from the quoted code.

Comment: You've got a few problems with your code, the first being uneven indentation. That makes it hard to see where your brackets line up. I've taken the liberty of cleaning that up; hopefully you can now spot the extra bracket.

Comment: Missing ) with the toast.

Comment: i hope you can help me  @MikeMcCaughan !

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a Parenthesis.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function detele() {
    toastr.warning("<div>confirmer la suppression?</div>" +
      "<div class ='btn-group pull-right'> " +
      "<button type ='button' id='confirmationYes' class ='btn btn-xs btn-primary'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></i>Oui</button>" +
      "<button type ='button' class ='btn btn-xs btn-default clear'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></i>Non</button>" +
      "</div>", 
      "DeleteConfirmation", 
      {
        allowHtml: true,
        closeButton: true,
        onShown: function() {
          $("#confirmationYes").click(function() {
              toastr.success("Done");
            });
          }
        };
      )};
</script>
```

note that in yours, the .click(function() { doesn't have a closing parenthesis.
Next time before posting, make sure you check that all the openings have closings.

Comment: thanks for your help but im still getting the same error !

Comment: try that, I swapped two that were in the wrong order.

Comment: also you had the wrong amount of closed brackets; you needed 4 and you only had 3.

Comment: could you please provide the source code you are trying this to get to work on so I could make it work?

Comment: <b:commandButton  icon="trash"  action="#{recBean.supprimer(item.idRec)}"  onclick="detele();"/>

Comment: could you put it into a jsfiddle?

Comment: You didn't syntax it correctly so I cannot determine what you are trying to say

Comment: how can i contact you mate ?

Comment: i cannot syntax it because the data is fetched from database so you will get noth as front end

Answer (score 0):

You forget to close your delete and onShown function. try this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function detele() {
        toastr.warning("<div>confirmer la suppression?</div>" +
          "<div class ='btn-group pull-right'> " +
          "<button type ='button' id='confirmationYes' class ='btn btn-xs btn-primary'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></i>Oui</button>" +
          "<button type ='button' class ='btn btn-xs btn-default clear'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></i>Non</button>" +
          "</div>", 
          "DeleteConfirmation", 
          {
            allowHtml: true,
            closeButton: true,
            onShown: function() {
              $("#confirmationYes").click(function() {
                  toastr.success("Done");
                });
              };
          });
        };
    </script>
```

Comment: unfortunately im still get the same eroor